# Monadic parsing of binary data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I am pretty new to Haskell, and my first project is to parse captured WLAN packets. A common pattern in parsing such packet is that a header field will define the structure of the remaining bytes. As a generic example, a packet can be formatted like this:

```
header + [payload A | payload B | ..]
```

where a flag field (can be a bitmap) in the header specifies what payload(s) are included in the packet. For a specific example of this format, please check out [radiotap](http://www.radiotap.org/).

[A similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517620/haskell-binary-parsing) suggests to just use a sequence of `parse` operations like this:

```
parseAll = do
    hdr <- parseHeader
    pa <- parsePayloadA
    pb <- parsePayloadB
```

However it seems cannot be applied in my case as the existence of payload `A` and `B` is defined by the header. In other word, the control flow of data parsing needs to follow a prior parsing result. I'd like to understand that if there is a generic way to parse binary data with this kind of pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `parseAll` uses some kind of **monadic** parser library (as can be seen from the usage of the `do` notation and the binds). The power of monads is exactly that your choice of `parsePayloadA` and `parsePayloadB` can depend on `hdr`: you have the full power of Haskell to inspect `hdr`.

So basically you can do something like

```
parseAll = do
    hdr <- parseHeader
    payload <- case somethingInTheHdr hdr of
       ThisIsAnA -> do
         a <- parsePayloadA
         return (PayloadA a)
       ThisIsAB -> do
         b <- parsePayloadB
         return (PayloadB b)
    -- can use body here, e.g.
    return (Packet hdr payload)
```

You have this power specifically because in the type of monadic bind:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

the arrow in `a -> m b` is the real Haskell function arrow, giving you all the power you need.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the type of "payload" in this case?

Comment: This is assuming you have two possible payloads, with `data Payload = PayloadA A | PayloadB B`

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the purpose of the Monad interface: to encode the dependency of a computation on the result of a preceding computation.

In your case it'll be something like the following:

```
parseAll = do
  shouldThePayloadABeParsed <- parseHeader
  if shouldThePayloadABeParsed
    then do
      pa <- parsePayloadA
      ...
    else do
      pb <- parsePayloadB
      ...
```

For your purposes I recommend reading the ["Taste of State: Parsers are Easy"](http://nikita-volkov.github.io/a-taste-of-state-parsers-are-easy/) post to get an understanding of how this kind of parsing works in Haskell, and the ["binary-parser"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-parser) package to do the parsing.